# Example of a pre-abelian category but not a semi-abelian category?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Wikipedia says that a semi-abelian category is a pre-abelian category in which for each morphism ${\displaystyle f}$ the induced morphism ${\displaystyle {\overline {f}}:\operatorname {coim} f\rightarrow \operatorname {im} f}$ is always a monomorphism and an epimorphism. But examples in my brain which is pre-abelian but not abelian are like Banach space and Hausdorff abelian topological groups, which are all semi-abelian. So can anyone give me an example which is pre-abelian but not semi-abelian?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the (abelian) category of diagrams $U\stackrel{\alpha}{\to}V\stackrel{\beta}{\to}W$ of vector spaces over a fixed field $k$.

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the full subcategory consisting of those diagrams where $V=\text{im}\alpha+\ker\beta$.

$\mathcal{D}$ is closed under taking quotients in $\mathcal{C}$, and so has cokernels, which are the same as in $\mathcal{C}$.

Every object $U\stackrel{\alpha}{\to}V\stackrel{\beta}{\to}W$ of $\mathcal{C}$ has a unique subobject $U\to(\text{im}\alpha+\ker\beta)\to W$ that is maximal subject to being in $\mathcal{D}$. So $\mathcal{D}$ has kernels: a kernel in $\mathcal{D}$ is the maximal $\mathcal{D}$-subobject of the kernel in $\mathcal{C}$.

So $\mathcal{D}$ is pre-abelian.

Now consider the obvious nonzero map from $k\stackrel{\sim}{\to}k\stackrel{\sim}{\to}k$ to $k\to0\to0$. The coimage in $\mathcal{D}$ of this map is $k\stackrel{\sim}{\to}k\to0$, and the image is $k\to0\to0$, and the natural map from the coimage to the image is not monic.

So $\mathcal{D}$ is not semi-abelian.

Comment: Hi! May I know how you came up with this example? Thanks!

Comment: @Pig It was more than a year and a half ago, and I don’t remember exactly. But I think I just experimented with removing objects from an abelian category (in this case the objects containing $0\to k\to k$ as a direct summand) in such a way that existence of kernels and cokernels was preserved.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your response - was curious since I couldn't really come up with examples myself here